# Is there a way to transform only some keys in Rails using transform_keys method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a hash that looks like this:

```
 "properties": [
    {
        "accommodates": 14,
        "adr": 1336.69,
        "host_id": 23724674,
        "property_id": 4576625,
        "bathrooms": 4.5,
        "bedrooms": 5,
        "business_ready": false,
        "cancellation": "strict",
        "check_in": "Anytime after 4PM",
        "check_out": "11AM",
        "cleaning_fee": 200,
        "days_a_ltm": 138,
        "days_b_ltm": 24,
        "days_r_ltm": 203,
        "extra_person_charge": 50,
        "img_count": 26,
        "img_cover": "",
        "instant_book": true,
        "last_calendar_update": "2018-02-16",
        "latitude": 39.7610167973274,
        "listed_dt": "2014-10-24",
        "listing_url": "rooms/4576625",
        "location": {
            "city": "Denver",
            "country": "United States",
            "msa": "Denver-Aurora-Lakewood, CO Metro Area",
            "neighborhood": [
                "Highland"
            ],
            "state": "Colorado",
            "zipcode": "80211"
        },
        "longitude": -105.008507384098,
        "minimum_stay": 2,
        "num_res_ltm": 64,
        "occ": 0.595308,
        "price_monthly": 17000,
        "price_nightly": 725,
        "price_weekly": 5600,
        "property_type": "Entire house",
        "rating_overall": 9.9,
        "response_rate": 100,
        "response_time": 229,
        "revenue": 271348,
        "reviews": 124,
        "room_type": "Entire home/apt",
        "scraped_dt": "2018-02-25",
        "security_deposit": 1000,
        "superhost": true,
        "title": "Huge Home in the Heart of Lohi! Groups Welcome!"
    },
    {
        "accommodates": 15,
        "adr": 781.576,
        "host_id": 14178014,
        "property_id": 9944575,
        "bathrooms": 5,
        "bedrooms": 6,
        "business_ready": true,
        "cancellation": "strict",
        "check_in": "Anytime after 3PM",
        "check_out": "12PM (noon)",
        "cleaning_fee": 200,
        "days_a_ltm": 46,
        "days_b_ltm": 7,
        "days_r_ltm": 312,
        "extra_person_charge": 15,
        "img_count": 49,
        "img_cover": "",
        "instant_book": true,
        "last_calendar_update": "2018-02-15",
        "latitude": 39.7349220878173,
        "listed_dt": "2015-12-11",
        "listing_url": "rooms/9944575",
        "location": {
            "city": "Denver",
            "country": "United States",
            "msa": "Denver-Aurora-Lakewood, CO Metro Area",
            "neighborhood": [
                "Capitol Hill"
            ],
            "state": "Colorado",
            "zipcode": "80218"
        }
 ]
```

There are some keys inside the properties array hashes that I want to change and I would like to use something simple like transform_keys or deep_transform_keys; however, those methods replace all keys which would require that a create a new map with all the keys below in order to change two or 3. In particular, I'm looking to rename adr, revenue, and occ. Does anybody know if there is a way to execute the transform_key or deep_transform_key method only on some keys? Something like:

```
hash_name.deep_transform_keys{|k| {:adr=>'adr_ltm', :revenue => 'revenue_ltm'}[k] if k == 'adr'||'revenue'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a specific reason you can't just loop through?

```
hash[:properties].each_with_index do |property, i|
  hash[:properties][i][:adr_ltm] = property.delete(:adr)
  hash[:properties][i][:revenue_ltm] = property.delete(:revenue)
end
```

Comment: The hash can be fairly large and nested so looping through seemed inefficient and ugly

Answer (score 1):

There are serializing/deserializing gems that help you in these situations. They allow both rendering json from your models and parsing json to update your Ruby objects. its soo much flexible to maintain code in long term.

```
# deserialize
song = Song.new
SongRepresenter.new(song).from_json('{"id":1, "title":"Fallout"}')
song.id    #=> 1
song.title #=> "Fallout"

# serialize
SongRepresenter.new(song).to_json #=> {"id":1, title":"Fallout"}
```

- [jsonapi-rb](http://jsonapi-rb.org/guides/deserialization/deserializing.html)
- [roar](http://trailblazer.to/gems/representable/3.0/api.html#parsing)

Comment: Thanks, this may actually help me a lot. I'm going to look at both to see if I can implement them for what I need. I'll post updates once I'm done checking.

Answer (score 0):

you can [monkey patch](https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/3-ways-to-monkey-patch-without-making-a-mess/) the private method in Class Hash,or re-implement your own one, this is the idea

```
class Hash


  private

    def _deep_transform_keys_in_object(object, &block)
      case object
      when Hash
        object.each_with_object({}) do |(key, value), result|
          # define what key you want to run
          return unless key != :key_name
          result[yield(key)] = _deep_transform_keys_in_object(value, &block)
        end
      when Array
        object.map {|e| _deep_transform_keys_in_object(e, &block) }
      else
        object
      end
    end
end
```

this method is used by deep_transform_keys in this way:

```
def deep_transform_keys(&block)
  _deep_transform_keys_in_object(self, &block)
end
```

this is the basic idea, not the fully functional code, you need make sure it work by yourself.